# After decoding a UTF-8 byte array to a string, find the original byte position of specific characters

Tags: c#, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a `byte[]` array which contains UTF-8 encoded characters. (The array can contain some raw byte sections which may correspond to invalid UTF-8 sequences.)

When I decode the array to a string, how can I determine which character in the string starts at which byte position in the array?

**Example**:
the byte array contains the encoded string `"pay attention, here come 10 raw bytes:%$�²& bla bla bla bla"`.

When I convert the whole array to a string, and search that string for the phrase `"10 raw bytes:"`, how can I tell at which index in the original byte array the phrase `"10 raw bytes:"` starts and ends?

Currently I am decoding my array with `decoder.GetChars(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length, charArray, 0);`

Comment: You should be searching for the string in the bytes, not the bytes in the string.  I would convert string "10 raw bytes:"  to bytes using Encoding.UTF8.ToBytes("10 raw bytes:") then searching in the byte array.  The using Array.Find() method to locate starting position.

Comment: That is a good point, although I would have to write my own "string search" methods for byte arrays. Array.Find() only works for finding a single byte. And it would prevent me from ever supporting regex for the search, which is not a concern right now, but might be at some point.